# Finding all snapshots of a specific EBS volume

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, snapshot

I want to get all the snapshots of a specific volume.

Lets say there is a volume whose volume-id is `vol-23fei9` and there are 6 different snapshots of that volume. I want to extract the snapshot-id of all the 6 snapshot taken from the volume `vol-23fei9`.

Is there any way to extract the information?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to realise that Snapshots are associated with Volumes (rather than the reverse).

This command will display **all snapshots associated with the volume:**

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filter "Name=volume-id,Values=vol-23fei9"
```

To **limit the output** to simply displaying the ID of the snapshots:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filter "Name=volume-id,Values=vol-23fei9" --query 'Snapshots[*].SnapshotId' --output text

snap-e0ded613
```

See: [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) documentation for [describe-snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [describe-snapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-snapshots.html) CLI command/API. Add a `--filter` that is the `volume-id`. This will return all snapshots for a given volume.